# Store path as variable

Tags: powershell, variables, output

The local package location for the Microsoft Office Access Runtime 2010 on my computer is C:\Windows\Installer\413e5.msi, however, for others the .msi name is different.

How can I go about storing this path as a variable to reference?

Answer (score 2):

Just like anything else you want to store in a variable, you assign it.

```
# (...) being whatever you want to store in $myvariable
$myvariable = ...
```

After that's done, you can reference it by the variables name. Here are some examples of string concatenating.

```
$path = 'C:\Windows\Installer\'
Join-Path -Path $path -ChildPath '412e5.msi' 
$path + '412e5.msi'
"${path}412e5.msi"
'{0}{1}' -f $path,'412e5.msi'
```

With all giving you the result of `C:\Windows\Installer\412e5.msi`.